# How to search the people in facebook using email-id?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on facebook application for ipad. I am using graph api for that. Can anyone tell me how to search the people on facebook by entering emailid ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find Facebook user (url to profile page) by known email address](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234651/find-facebook-user-url-to-profile-page-by-known-email-address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the facebook profile of a person by using following graph api url

https://graph.facebook.com/search?fields=id,name,link&q=(friends_email)&type=user&access_token=(accesstoken)

It will give the results if the person is in our friend list. For non-friend it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible! Facebook only provide this functionality for users who use Facebook site  and this functionality probably will never be exposed via API.

**Update:**
There is a possibility to search by email via Graph API but it's limited to your contacts and cannot be used to search other users (See response in [BUG #167188686695750](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/167188686695750)):

> searching for users is intended to be a user to user function only, for use in finding new friends or searching by email to find existing contacts on Facebook.

This actually means that you required to query API with active user `access_token` and cannot do such search using application `access_token` or anonymously.

Furthermore this functionality is currently broken (See [Searching Facebook profile with email address is no more working with Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292220680814266)). This bug (as of 23/02/2012) marked as fixed and fix probably will be pushed soon.

Comment: It was possible up until dec 2011 when they broke it without notice. There is a bug logged for it.

Comment: @OffBySome, Although this bug is marked as fixed this functionality isn't documented in any way and doesn't provide way to search for all people but just "your contacts", I've updated my answer to clarify this.